# how to get merged changes in json from gerrit code review

Tags: json, gerrit

Is there a way i can get a json of all the changes in gerrit code review?

for example get all the merged changes from gerrit.aokp.co? It would be even better if i could get the changes from the previous day only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `query` command on the ssh command line, adding the `--format json` option to get the data in JSON format.

To get merged changes use the `status:merged` query operator.

There is no query operator to get changes within a specific time range, but you can use the `age` operator to specify an amount of time passed since the change was last updated.

For example to get all changes merged within the last day:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 user@review gerrit query --format json status:merged age:1day
```

Note that by default this will return a limit of 500 results.  To see more, you need to either increase the limit (if you're an administrator) or use multiple queries making use of the `--resume_sortkey` option.

See the documentation for more details:

- [Query command](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/cmd-query.html)
- [Search operators](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/user-search.html)

Comment: thanks, the way i got it was by going to http://gerrit.aokp.co/query?format=JSON&q=status:merged. I want to implement this in an android app, so i think my way would be easier. Ill mark your answer right since it is still right. Thanks!

Comment: The aokp server is running Gerrit 2.7-rc3.

After 2.8 is released it'll be possible to do more of what you want using the REST API.